# Could this question deletion be explained to me?

Tags: discussion

This question was deleted by a diamond mod: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216260/

I'd appreciate it if the reason for the deletion could be explained.

I realise that it was not possible to explain the exact reason for the error reported in the question. But it was certainly possible to explain where the error could be found, and how to investigate further. Do we really not accept questions of this nature?

**Update:** Looking at the edit history, it seems the asker, for some reason, edited the question and removed important details. Perhaps that contributed.

Comment: Can you provide a bit of better context for <10K members as to what type of moderation decision was made, i.e. due to language/quality/security?

Comment: I'm taking a shot in the dark and guessing the OP requested deletion.

Comment: @Compass all I can see is deletion by diamond mod. Perhaps asker requested that. I suspect asker has been told off by bosses for revealing confidential details.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, they were and that's why it was removed.  The user requested deletion because they mistakenly included code they shouldn't have.

Comment: @Servy I'm coming round to that too. Based on edits and comments. Thanks.

Comment: @bluefeet Thank you! I'm content now. I just wanted to know why and understand whether or not such questions were valid still.

Comment: @bluefeet Of course, some of us can still see it. What if user really wanted it removed, so mods and 10k users could not see it. Would SE oblige? Asking out of curiosity now.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes.  We can request to have a revision removed from a post.

Comment: I've grown fond lately of giving people kudos for asking questions about apparently confusing moderator activity in a constructive way... so here; have some kudos!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I wasn't the moderator who deleted the question, but it was requested by the OP.  Unfortunately, they included some code they shouldn't have and flagged requesting the post be removed.

Comment: As an addendum: If a user includes something they shouldn't in a post, our response is to delete the post; ask for a revision wipe from the Community Team, and then undelete the post after.   Sometimes if we don't know why they want it deleted (because they don't tell us) and we don't have a reason not to delete it, this procedure isn't followed.

Comment: As the moderator who deleted this, I did so because in addition to pointing out that it had potentially sensitive code, the question asker also thought that what they asked wouldn't be of broader use to anyone else. I thought they had a point and decided that the strength of David's answer wasn't enough to outweigh their argument.